# Google Apps Scripting Running a Script Based on a Variable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Okay, I've been a coding for a little while and have had the chance to do a number of things.

One issue I'd like to find a more elegant way is running scripts based on the value of a variable.

At the moment I'm doing it like this.

```
    if (ScriptName == 'overnightRun' ) {
      overnightRun();
    } 
    if (ScriptName == 'resetAnalysisSheets' ) {
      resetAnalysisSheets();
    } 
    if (ScriptName == 'resetActiveSheetFormulae' ) {
      resetActiveSheetFormulae();
    } 
    if (ScriptName == 'saveRemainingContractSheets' ) {
      saveRemainingContractSheets();
    } 
    if (ScriptName == 'saveAllContractSheets' ) {
      saveAllContractSheets();
    } 
    if (ScriptName == 'saveCurrentContractSheet' ) {
      saveCurrentContractSheet();
    } 
    if (ScriptName == 'clearDataSheets' ) {
      clearDataSheets();
    }
```

Surely there must be a better way. Something more like this.

```
    run.script(ScriptName);
```

Anyone any ideas? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
function testFunction() {
  var ScriptName = "Alibaba";
  var p = "Open sesame!"
  this[ScriptName](p);
}

function Alibaba(p) {
  Logger.log(p);
}
```

Leave the parameter `p` blank if nothing is to be passed.

Comment: Super! You may want to [accept the anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks, I've just done that. Working out my way around Stack Overflow as well ;-)